# Joomla homepage slideshow not working correctly on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, joomla

I have a slideshow that is running in the Homepage, but only in Firefox browser the slideshow is shifted to the right instead of being center. 
I updated to the latest Firefox.
I have Joomla version 2.5.27
[www.divine-culture.com](http://www.divine-culture.com)

I made a little change to layout.css, by changing the overflow from hidden to visible.

```
#yjsg1, #yjsg2, #yjsg3, #yjsg4, #yjsg5, #yjsg6, #yjsg7, #yjsgbodytop, #yjsgbodybottom {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;   [ changed this to visible] 
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
```

this fixed the issue, but it shifted all the writings on the page down, so I changed it back to hidden and I have the issue with the slideshow.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your site so we can inspect the element?

Comment: www.divine-culture.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is remove the following:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

from the code you've provides in your question.

Comment: That still makes all the writings on the page to move down. You can check the website now.

Comment: @JFA - In which case, keep the overflow hidden and add `#yjsg2 { overflow: visible; }` as a new CSS rule